# How can I convert a variant VT_DATE to a string and include the time at midnight

Tags: string, date, locale, changetype

I currently convert dates from variant format to string using the VariantChangeType (or CComVariant::ChangeType). That works well, except when the time portion of the variant value is midnight. In that case, the time is simply omitted from the converted string.

A timestamp of 2015/10/07 03:40:00 is converted to a string just as you would expect: "10/7/2015 03:40:00 AM" (using my regional settings).

But a timetamp of 2015/1007 00:00:00 is converted to this string: "10/7/2015" (no time portion included).

I'm trying to preserve that midnight time, and keep the regional settings in use too. I've looked at _strftime_l() - it does include a time in the converted string, but doesn't appear to use the regional settings, even when one is provided via _get_current_locale().

I'm using C++ on Windows.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Maybe add the tag of the relevant programming language you are using to attract more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I found a way to resolve this. Windows has two API calls that will format the date and time with regional settings: GetDateFormat() and GetTimeFormat(). They each take a SYSTEMTIME structure, an output buffer, and a locale specifier. On return, the output buffer contains the date (or time) converted to a string matching the locale and regional settings in use.

I also found that _strftime_l() will actually use regional settings if you call setlocal(LC_ALL, "") first. I was a bit leery of using that method as it may have side affects I'm not aware of.